# Highcharts server post request issue

Tags: post, highcharts, http-post

I'm sending a post request to a highcharts server however I'm not getting back what I expect.

```
{
    title: {
        text: 'Volume Capacity Used (GB)'
    }, 
    subtitle: {
        text: 'For the month of July'
    }, 
    plotOptions: {
        series: { 
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: { 
        startOnTick: true, 
        endOnTick: true, 
        showFirstLabel: true, 
        min: 1372636800000, 
        minorTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, 
        type: 'datetime', 
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        }
    }, 
    yAxis: [{
        labels: {
            formatter: function(){ 
                return this.value + ' GB';
            }
        }, 
        endOnTick: true, 
        min: 0, 
        max: 1890, 
        title: {
            text: 'Capacity Used (GB)'
        }
    },
    {
        labels:{
            formatter:function(){ 
                var max=1890, min=this.axis.linkedParent.min,range=max-min; 
                return (Math.round((this.value-min)/(range)*100)) + ' %';
            }
        }, 
        linkedTo:0, 
        opposite:true, 
        title: { 
            text: 'Percentage Used (%)'
        }
    }], 
    series: [{
        "data":[{
            "x":1372638600000,
            "y":1362.69
         },
         {
            "x":1372640400000,
            "y":1362.7
         },
         {
            "x":1372643100000,
            "y":1362.7
         },
         {
            "x":1372644900000,
            "y":1362.72
         },
         {
            "x":1372647600000,
            "y":1362.72
         }],
         "name":"GraphName"
    }]
};
```

My post request is a lot bigger than that, but I removed some of the series data as I don't need to put it all here.

What I expect to get is a graph stretching across the whole month, however what I'm getting is a graph that just shows the 1st of July and nothing else.

I assume it's something to do with the POST request. It does however work for some other months using the same POST request with different data.

[Failed Graph](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/6890/o1wt.png)

[Succsessful Graph](http://img404.imageshack.us/img404/1901/3tsf.png)

Any ideas?

[Longer Post Request](http://justpaste.it/3kay)

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced you example here: http://jsfiddle.net/q5aMr/ (`based on your source code`) and exported chart looks like the same. Which browser and version of Highcharts do you use?

Comment: Ahh perhaps it is an issue with a large amount of data.. I've updated my question to add a link to the full post request.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to either disable or increase the turboThreshold in the highcharts configuration

[Turbo Threshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold)

example:

```
series: [{
    turboThreshold: 10000,
    "data":[{
        "x":1372638600000,
        "y":1362.69
     },
     {
        "x":1372640400000,
        "y":1362.7
     },
     {
        "x":1372643100000,
        "y":1362.7
     },
     {
        "x":1372644900000,
        "y":1362.72
     },
     {
        "x":1372647600000,
        "y":1362.72
     }],
     "name":"GraphName"
}]
```

To disable it altogether, I would change the turboThreshold value to 0.